# Creating Associative Arrays in PHP/MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a column in my profileTable called "Associations"... I am trying to query profiles relative to the associations.

```
$sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM profileTable  WHERE  Keyword_ID LIKE
'%".$getKeyID."%' ORDER BY  Associations <> 'School of Engineering 
and Computer Science', Associations AND LaName ASC LIMIT $start,$end");
```

I am able to index profiles by education but not by Association.

```
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $key = $row['Keyword_Name'];
        $keyID = $row['Keyword_ID'];
        $fname = $row['FirName'];
        $lname = $row['LaName'];
        $mname = $row['MName'];
        $suffix = $row['Suffix'];
        $title = $row['Title'];
        $title2 = $row['Title2'];
        $title3 = $row['Title3'];
        $education = $row['Education'];
        $education2 = $row['Education2'];
        $education3 = $row['Education3'];
        $dept = $row['Dept'];
        $phone1 = $row['PH1'];
        $phone2 = $row['PH2'];
        $email = $row['Email'];
        $photo = $row['Photo'];
        $bio = $row['BioLK'];
        $website = $row['Website'];
        $assocs = $row['Associations'];

$actions=array('School of Engineering and Computer Science'=>'Computer Science 
       and Engineering');
```

I need to relate the Associations with the $key(word) so if a user clicks on a keyword "Computers" it will relate to "School of Engineering and Computer Science" and index those in the "School of Engineering and Computer Science" first.

This works fine with other columns like "Education" but can't seem to get it to work with my associative array. Any ideas?

example sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c1802/7/0

Comment: question: why are you unpacking that row into a million variables?

Comment: ?? @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans explain...

Comment: no, that was the entire question. You have a data container with all your data, why would you unpack it to 20 variables instead of using the associative data array in the section of code that needs to use it? This just makes your code unnecessarily huge, without any real benefit ($title1 is just as legible as $data["title1"], for instance)

Comment: On a more getting-an-answer related note, you probably also want to post a http://sqlfiddle.com/ link to show what your data actually looks like, with the queries easy to replicate.

Comment: Here is my attempt to create this query in the easiest way I can. See this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c1802/7/0 @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans

Comment: See this working [**sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/944ad/1)

Comment: @davidstrachan works perfect but what about my associative array? It isn't indexing my associations to at the top still. How would I get this to work?

Comment: Don't understand ! `$row` is associative array,the SQL query produces it

Comment: Well I tried this but it only displays those with the keyword=""... i only want to index those first and the other outside of the association display lastly. @davidstrachan

Comment: Like [**THIS**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/944ad/2)

Comment: @davidstrachan you just made me a happy woman. Thanks! This worked perfectly...

Comment: I have answered this question. Have a look at it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query lists output ordered as required.

```
SELECT * FROM mediaContacts ORDER BY  associations DESC,lname ASC
```

[**Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/944ad/2)

As `associations` has `School of Engineering and Computer Science` as the last alpha record this works.

If `School of Engineering and Computer Science` is not the  last alpha record this fails and another method is required.

Comment: Thanks @davidstrachan this solved my query... and isolated my association according to my clicked keyword just as expected. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following

Change

`while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {`

to

`while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {`

It will Return an associative array that corresponds to the fetched row and moves the internal data pointer ahead.

Comment: I thought this too but it instead did not return any results. With fetch_array it returns the results, just doesn't index the "Associations" first. Hmmm...

Comment: I've added a sqlfiddle at: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c1802/7/0 if you change "assoc" back to "array" it works...